# A more efficient way of aggregating a random sample from pandas dataframe and iteratively append the mean of sampled df in an empty dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, aggregate, sampling

I am trying to take out a random sample from my df, take mean of all columns in a single row series, using df_sample.mean(axis =0) and then appending this series to an empty dataframe and I want 1 million such rows. I am getting the result but it is taking too much time to run. Can someone please suggest an efficient way to do this ?

```
train = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range (1000000):

    df_sample  = df_2.sample(n=100)
    row = df_sample.mean(axis=0)
    train = train.append(row,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I'm confused. You sample 100 records from the dataframe, compute the mean of each row, which gives you 100-dimensions column vector, and then append it as a row to a new dataframe? What's the purpose of this?

Comment: to get an aggreagated dataset having continous variables (because of mean). My original dataset is having categorical variables only. SO, thats why

Answer (score 0):

Here's a faster way to do, this would result in 1 million (10 lakh) rows:

**Method 1: Sampling using pandas inbuilt**

```
n_times = 1000000
values = [df_2.sample(n=1).mean(axis=0, numeric_only=True) for _ in range (n_times)]
train = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['mean_col'])
```

**Method 2: Sampling using numpy**

```
def f1():
    return np.mean(df_2.values[np.random.randint(0, df.shape[0])])

def f2():
    return df_2.iloc[np.random.randint(0, df.shape[0])].mean(axis=0, numeric_only=True)

values = [f1() for _ in range(n_times)]
train = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['mean_col'])

values = [f2() for _ in range(n_times)]
train = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['mean_col'])
```

Comment: Not the faster way, taking almost same time